# Copy function works, how to strip a comma code to it?

Tags: javascript

A user named prasanth provided someone else with working javascript to copy something by clicking on it:

```
function copy(that){
var inp =document.createElement('input');
document.body.appendChild(inp)
inp.value =that.textContent
inp.select();
document.execCommand('copy',false);
inp.remove();
}

<p onclick="copy(this)">hello man</p>
```

I tried adding a replace code in there so that it removes commas from the copied text but it doesn't work.  So if I click on 1,950 for example, I would like the copied result to be 1950.  The numbers are always different this was only an example.  It seems easy but I never could understand javascript it seems to never do what I want.

Comment: You could do `inp.value = that.textContent.replace(/,/g, '');`

Comment: "I tried adding a replace code" — it is hard to debug code we can't see.

Comment: Thanks shrys that worked.  I used that code except I didn't add it to the inp.value line thanks again.

Comment: glad i was of help

Answer (score 3):

```
<script>
function copy(that){
var inp = document.createElement('input');
document.body.appendChild(inp)
inp.value = that.textContent.replace(/,/g, "");
inp.select();

document.execCommand('copy',false);
inp.remove();
}
</script>

<p onclick="copy(this)">hello,man</p>
```

Notice where I did the replacement on line 5

Comment: Good point, In such a case Shrys's answer would me more suitable. I have edited the answer accordingly